# Code to Change Cell Value in PowerPoint(Office 365) VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm making a game inside PPT for cybersecurity awareness month for my company. I'm using VBA to make a couple of extra features that make it slightly nicer than just a jeopardy style quiz. I've already gotten buttons to work (action buttons) that can hide pictures / make them visible, as well as a button that can change the text on another slide (E.g button on slide 2 sets global variable to "boop" and then changes textbox on slide 1).

Right now i'm trying to figure out the code to do the same thing with a table made inside the slide. The table is already made (and renamed "testtable").

I want to select for example A2, and then make A2 = boop. I've tried a bunch of different code but can't figure out how to change the cell value.

Thanks for help

This code has worked perfectly to change text on a different slide

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("textbox").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = randomInt
```

I've tried things like

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("testtable").table.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = randomInt
```

I've tried changing the `.text` to `.value`. i've tried a bunch of other things but how card can it be to change a single cell?!

Comment: For the future: Don't just assume something has a property, there are docs that describe the language quite well. ( See @bm13563s Answer). Another way is to set a Watch on a variable or an object and then explore it, this is a very easy way to get a view "inside" an object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("testtable").Table.Cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = randomInt
```

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.table).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've been looking through the docs and also StackExchange and still it hasn't been super easy (I way prefer Java...but I have to use PPT)